# Docking user controls in a Tab component

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to dock two user controls in a tab component. I have set the dock property in my tab component to fill. But when i maximize the window the component in the user control stay in the same location in the tab component. What should i do ?

Comment: Have you **also** set the `Dock` of your UserControl(s) to `Fill`?

Comment: just tried docking a gridview, and some panels. And that didnt help. when i maximize the form the components does not keep their position

Answer (score 0):

When you dock fill your controls in a parent component, make it sure that every edge of your controls is in every edge of the parent component also.

Comment: so i have to make sure that the size of the tab control is the same size as the user control ?

Comment: By the way, I'm just confused, what user control are you using? And as far as I know every time you set any controls to dock fill it will automatically fill in the parent container. Maybe you want also to make your tab control to fill to its parent container. Or maybe you can set the anchor properties to it.

Comment: I want my components to have a default position. So when maximizing it would still have the same position in the window. So it has to be top rightif its maximized or not.

Comment: I think you need to set the 'anchor' properties of that certain component...if you want it top right always, set anchor right and anchor top for it.

Comment: i have user control with components. Should i set the anchor property on my components in the user control or on my tab component in the main frame ?

Comment: If your tab is in the expected position as soon as you maximize the application, then you don't have to set anchor for it. It depends on what control will you want to remain at a certain position.

Comment: i have tried to use the anchoring property on a test project with same components. (2 panels). When i run the form with the 2 panels in it and set the anchor top TOP-RIGHT it works. If i do the same in my User Control and then insert it into a tab in the mainform it doesn't work